# Kohana 2.3.4 ORM and Regex database method

Tags: php, regex, orm, kohana

I'm attempting to use Kohana's regex() database method with ORM to search for a word. I was using the like() method originally, but the results weren't what I wanted. Basically what I need to do is search a phrase for a certain word. I've used basic regular expressions like this before, but I must be doing something wrong. I've tried the following without any success:

```
$prod_name = ORM::factory("product")->regex("prod_name", "^" . $searchArray[$i] . "$")->find_all();

$prod_name = ORM::factory("product")->regex("prod_name", "/b" . $searchArray[$i] . "/b")->find_all();

$prod_name = ORM::factory("product")->regex("prod_name", "/\b" . $searchArray[$i] . "\b/")->find_all();
```

Kohana's documentation states that regex() works the same as like(), but it's not. This works fine:

```
$prod_name = ORM::factory("product")->like("prod_name",$searchArray[$i])->find_all();
```

As does this:

```
$prod_name = ORM::factory("product")->like("prod_name",$searchArray[$i] . "%", FALSE)->find_all();
```

Comment: This should work. Can you give an example of a `$searchArray[$i]` value that you are passing?

Comment: an example would be a string of any type. "brown shoe", "leather coat", etc. The "prod_name" field in the database is text. I've also tried to use the actual text I'm searching for instead of a variable like this: "^shoe$". Still, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through some further research, trial & error, I found the answer. Kohana's database method isn't using normal regular expressions, but MySql's version. In my situation, I'm searching for words in a phrase and would use the following (I'm using "shoe" as my example)

```
[[:<:]]shoe
```

Would find words that begin with shoe

```
shoe[[:>:]]
```

Would find words that end with shoe

```
[[:<:]]shoe[[:>:]]
```

Would only find words that are shoe

The code that ended up working for me is:

```
$prod_name = ORM::factory("product")->regex("prod_name", "[[:<:]]" . $searchArray[$i])->find_all();
```

Hope this helps someone else.